# Pi 2 usb camera stream hosted by third party

Tags: camera, motion

I have a Pi2 running Raspbian and I have a USB camera attached to it (I have checked, the camera is compatible and powering is OK).

I am trying to achieve the following: I want to be able to remotely (outside my LAN) monitor the camera stream, but I have no external IP address.

For the camera software I'm planning on using 'motion' (there is plenty of HOWTO articles out there). However, since I don't have an external IP, I want somehow the Pi to upload the camera stream on a 3rd party service, such as OneDrive or similar, so I can access it there.

Anyone done something similar?

Comment: I am now thinking of doing this: http://www.sudobob.com/raspberry-pi-web-cam-on-sensr-net/

Comment: Looks like a good idea, especially if you don't have a server space.

Answer (score 1):

You've written that you don't have an external IP. I assume that you're connected to internet via your ISP NAT and hence can not access your device directly using external IP. Well, in that case, you can use remote ssh port forward to a amazon t2 or google cloud and configure that server so that you can access your device stream.

You just need to forward port.

Here is an example.

ssh -N -R [remote-port]:localhost:[local-port] [serverUser]@[server-ip]

You can make use of autossh to make your connection more stable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, this sounds like the way to go. But won't that forward just the SSH port? I have assumed that the video stream would be over HTTP. Also, can you please give me some pointers regarding how would I go about setting up google cloud SSH forward. I never knew this is possible. I can't find a definitive answer over at google.

Comment: No. It can forward any port via ssh tunnel. Additional reads : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html